# How can i refer to specific element in JSON list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got the following profile, called leadfree.json. Inside it, I get the following:

```
{"type": "profile", "data": [[0, 25], [90, 150], [180, 183], [211, 237], [234, 184], [313, 26]], "name": "leadfree"}
```

In one of my function in a .js file, I got the following function:

```
ws_status.onmessage = function(e)
{
    x = JSON.parse(e.data)
    ...
    if (x.heat > 0.5) {//do something}   //example
    ...
}
```

I would like to refer to the [234,184]. Id like to say that if the data is right now whatever is in 5th block of data, id like to do something

```
if data = [x5,y5] do something.
```

How would I do that? I'm quite new to JSON and just trying to implement some changes to open-source web-application.

Here is my try:

```
if (x.[5]) {window.alert("!");}
```

The values will not stay constant, which is why I can't just use the values.

For now, I also can't test it, since it's linked to a hardware application, on Linux.

Comment: Should I have missed something... here is the whole function: https://textuploader.com/dznkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array in JS is 0 indexed so you need to use index 4 to get the info in position 5 like :

```js
var e = JSON.parse('{"type": "profile", "data": [[0, 25], [90, 150], [180, 183], [211, 237], [234, 184], [313, 26]], "name": "leadfree"}');

console.log(e.data[4]); //result [234, 184]
```

Now when you get the array at the desired position you could perform the flow you want.

Comment: I can't actually place the profile inside the ws_status. It exists as a separate file which can be modified via the web application, and also sometimes other profiles are used, with different values. How could I refer to e.data[4] without changing x = JSON.parse(e.data)? Would it be possible to do y = JSON.parse(e.data[4]) and just use     if (y) {window.alert("!");}

Comment: _I can't actually place the profile inside the ws_status_ Not sure what you mean ?!! `e.data` in my example is just following what your post provide, give us the value of `x` if you want to get the data from it, so we can provide reel life example;

Comment: Yes sure you can use `y = JSON.parse(e.data[4])` why not, but instead you can also : `x[4]`

Comment: I mean that this {"type": "profile", "data": [[0, 25], [90, 150], [180, 183], [211, 237], [234, 184], [313, 26]], "name": "leadfree"} is inside the file called leadfree.json. The values will change depending on whether the user uses leadfree.json or leaded.json or newprofile.json etc. The user creates those profiles within the web-app, therefore I cant just place the values inside of JSON.parse().

Comment: oh okay x[4] must be what I needed. Thank you.